# C# Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am getting an "Index was outside the bounds of the array." at dr1[1].ToString().

I have table contribution_master with 3 columns: type_id (int), name (varchar(20), amount (float).
I want to extract all the amount rows.

```
SqlConnection SQLCon1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PayrollConnStr"].ConnectionString.ToString());

    SqlCommand SQLCmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT amount FROM contribution_master", SQLCon1);

    try
    {
        SQLCon1.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr1 = SQLCmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            employer_epf = Convert.ToDouble(dr1[0].ToString());
            employer_admin = Convert.ToDouble(dr1[1].ToString());
            employer_edli = Convert.ToDouble(dr1[2].ToString());
            employer_admin_edli = Convert.ToDouble(dr1[3].ToString());
            employer_esi = Convert.ToDouble(dr1[4].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string errorMessage = "Error ";
        errorMessage += ex.Message;
        lblWarn.Text = errorMessage;
        lblWarn.Visible = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        SQLCon1.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dr1[x]` value relates to the position of the column it has read from the database.

The SQL you specify `SELECT amount FROM contribution_master` will return the `amount` column, however the data in this can only be accessed either using `dr1[0]` or `dr1["amount"]`.

`while (dr1.Read())` will iterate through each row of data in a loop until there is no more. However, if you need to access each row specifically, you might be better off filling the data into a datatable and assigning the values from there.

For example:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd1);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

employer_epf = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
employer_admin = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1][0].ToString());
employer_edli = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[2][0].ToString());
employer_admin_edli = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[3][0].ToString());
employer_esi = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[4][0].ToString());
```

Hopefully this helps, but would it not be easier to have the axis of your table the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

You're only returning one field from your query (amount) so there is only one field in the datareader (field 0)

Each call to `datareader.Read()` returns a single row. If you want subsequent rows, call `Read()` again.

So, in your code...

```
if (dr1.Read())
{
    employer_epf = Convert.ToDouble(dr1[0].ToString()); 
    if (dr1.Read())
    {
        employer_admin = Convert.ToDouble(dr1[0].ToString()); 
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Or you can populate a `DataTable` that will return all the rows at once.

Answer (score 0):

Change SELECT statement. (You've select `amount` column from the table)

```
SELECT * FROM contribution_master
```